# Can't send the correct value to the Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal

I have C# (WindowsForm) Application and I want to insert values into a database.

The information I insert into the database is the name of a product, his category and his cost, which is decimal(5,2).

However, when I try to insert a value like 1,90 , it only inserts 1,00. By that I want to say it only inserts the numbers before the comma, and then just add two zeros after the comma.

I already tried with this code:

```
decimal varcost = costprod.Value;
MySqlCommand command_addprod = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (name, cost, id_category) VALUES ('" + nameprod.Text + "','" + varcost + "'," + getidcat + ")");
```

And this code:

```
decimal varcost = costprod.Value;
MySqlCommand command_addprod = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (name, cost, id_category) VALUES ('" + nameprod.Text + "'," + varcost + "," + getidcat + ")");
```

The difference between this two codes is that the first one have quotation marks and the second one doesn't.

With the first code, it gives me the error I said. With the second code, it gives me an error like: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Every help is welcome!

---

**Edit:**

Now I tried with a different code:

```
string getidcat = catprod.SelectedItem.ToString();
        try
        {
            decimal varpreco = precoprod.Value;
            string varnome = nomeprod.Text;
            MySqlConnection mConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server = localhost; port=3307; database = startselling; user = root; password ='usbw';");                
            var sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO produtos (designacao, preco_unitario, id_categoria) VALUES ('@nome', @preco, (select id_categoria FROM categorias WHERE designacao = @categoria)";

            //Create mysql command and pass sql query
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, mConn))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", varnome);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preco", varpreco);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoria", getidcat);
                mConn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mConn.Close();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Succeeded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

(Some variables are different but don't bother with that)

I think I know where is the error, but I don't know how to solve it.

I think the error is on the variable "varpreco" because it contains values with a comma, and as this makes confusion with the commas of sql code, it gives an error.

Now maybe if I changed the comma from the variable to a dot, it should work. The problem is that I don't know how to use it.

If someone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Parameters. Read about them, use them, learn to love them even. They will fix all your problems with formatting on input and prevent SQL injection before you even know what that is.

Comment: Ahahah ok! I will learn more about them and learn how to love them! Thanks

Comment: It seems the comma separator for digit and decimal is causing confusion. Also please make sure your column type in database to store cost has got up to 3 decimal storage configuration.

Comment: I already noticed the problem was in the comma separator...the database has decimal(5,2) because I only need 2 decimal cases.

Comment: [`AddWithValue` considered harmful](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). (Some of the issues don't apply with MySQL as opposed to SQL Server, but some do.) Specify the actual type of the parameters, including the precision. There is no need to bother with any string manipulation of a `Decimal` if it's passed as a `Decimal`, and the decimal separator is completely irrelevant in that case.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to set the locale (German?) so that the "decimal point" would be ",".

Answer (score 2):

The code below is how you would add parameters for your command

```
MySqlCommand command_addprod = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (name, cost, id_category) VALUES (@nameprod, @varcost, @getidcat)";

command_addprod.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameprod", nameprod.text);
command_addprod.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varcost", varcost);
command_addprod.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getidcat", getidcat);
```

Comment: I already make these changes, as you can see o my question (I edited it). However it continues not working. I think it as something to do with the variable which contains "2,80" instead of "2.80"

Comment: If you think it is the commas, do this: varpreco.Replace(",", "") or  varpreco.Replace(",", ".");

Comment: Ok, I did it, and know why but it doesn't replace.

Comment: I make it like this: decimal varpreco = precoprod.Value;
                string varprecostring = precoprod.Value.ToString();
                varprecostring.Replace(",", ".");
                varpreco = Convert.ToDecimal(varprecostring);